# How to get VLC media player to recognize the Meta (Windows) key?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

I'm using VLC 1.0 on Windows XP and I've been trying to setup some global keybindings for skipping forward/back, etc.

It doesn't seem to recognize the Meta key. If I hold the Meta key and press the other key I want it just registers the other key by itself... What gives?

Comment: The Windows key is for Window's functions and not third-party apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLC just doesn't support using the <kbd>Win</kbd> key.

You can use AutoHotkey to work around this though. For example, this would map <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, which you could then assign in the VLC window.

`#o::!^o`

Comment: Is this documented regarding VLC? If so you get accepted.

Comment: No idea. The fact that it just flat out doesn't work was good enough for me =)  It's also a very common problem in hotkey controls.

Comment: works for me :)